# App engine Datastore cache or memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have read that the datastore read request in the App engine get cached and subsequent reads performed on the same entity are fast.

So if i read an entity from datastore, are there any tangible benefits of storing the entity in the memcache explicitly for later fetches? Or would the datastore caching serve with sufficient efficiency?

Comment: If you use ndb, ndb will take care. If you use db, you have to memcache yourself. Ndb is the preferred way of interacting with the datastore. Ndb has  lost of other benefits to speed up your io.

Comment: Remember ndb only caches get requests and not queries.  If you have a function/method that performs a query you may want to consider caching those results or do key's only queries and then gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Datastore caching' you refer to is implemented using *memcache* under the hood anyway, so you won't gain from additional explicit caching of these entities.

Python's *ndb* API and Java's *Objectify* both provide *memcache*-based automated caching for exactly this scenario.  Of course, you can still use *memcache* independently for additional application caching.

Comment: Note that queries are not cached, only strict get_by_id operations are cached.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi  Thanks for the clarification (I believe Objectify also does some caching on query results).